# Create an instance and destroy the previous instance

Tags: java, instance

I created a static method who create a JTabbedPane and every call a new JTabbedPane is created but I want when I call that method, a new instance (JTabbedPane) is created and the previous instance will be destroyed.

Code :

```
public  static void create(ColumnsUI cols, SiteTypePannelUI siteType){      
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT); 
    /* code */
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? In Java there is the Garbage Collector who destroys the unreferenced objects, you do not need explicitly to manage that like in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just create an object, then stop refering to it from any variable, it will eventually be garbage collected.

As for GUI elements, I assume you added your JTabbedPane on a pannel or some other UI element. By doing so, some variable is refering to your JTabbedPane. To get rid of this reference you need to remove your JTabbedPane from the pannel.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(java.awt.Component)

Note: If you have registered any listener, you will also need to unregister them. If not, you will continue refering to the component and will have inadvertently created a memory leak. See Java Lapsed Listener.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no more reference to the old instance, then it is gonna be destroyed by the garbage collector when necessary.

Comment: Note sure 'necessary' is the right term. But yes. If an object lacks a reference to it it will eventually be released by the JVM.

Comment: "Necessary" as in: "when GB kicks in to free memory"